# Oracle number data type issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, rdbms

I'm trying to save a number of certain characters(let's say 4) in my oracle 11g db. My numbers has a leading zero 
such 0100 0101 etc when i say the data. Why does oracle truncate the leading zero. Is it possible to avoid this. I really want the leading zero to get saved. Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to display the number with a leading zero then use:

```
to_char(my_number,'fm0000')
```

If you *really* need to store the number with a leading zero then store it as a varchar2, because what you have there is a string that consists only of digits, not a number.

Answer (score 3):

The `TO_CHAR` answers above are best, but they need a tweak because `TO_CHAR(number, '0000')` will add leading zeros *plus* a leading space, which is a placeholder in case there's a negative sign:

```
SELECT '[' || TO_CHAR(123, '0000') || ']' "Format" FROM DUAL;

Format
-------
[ 0123] <-- note the leading space
```

To get rid of the space, either LTRIM or use the FM qualifier in the format string:

```
SELECT '[' || TO_CHAR(123, 'FM0000') || ']' "Format" FROM DUAL;

Format
-------
[0123] <-- no more leading space
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the leading zero, then store the number as a `char()` for fixed length values or `varchar()` (or `varchar2()`) for variable length values.

Numbers are stored in a binary format, which has no concept of leading zeros.

Comment: The explanation is good but the solution - store a number as a string - is Teh Suck!  Leading zeroes are a display issue and should be handled in the client.

Comment: @APC . . . I can think of no case where leading zeros have been important and I would want to store values as numbers -- not zip codes, not account numbers, not customer ids.  Leading zeros are most emphatically not a display issue, they are an indication that what looks like a number does not behave like a number and probably shouldn't be treated as such in the database.

Comment: Okay, I think we're at cross-purposes here.  You're talking about character strings where all the characters are in the range ascii 48 - 57.  Like telephone numbers or IP addresses.  I agree such  things should be stored as varchars. But as far as actual numbers go, leading zeroes is simply a client issue. We don't know whether the OP is talking about strings of digits or actual numbers.

Comment: So my point is, you need to clarify what you mean by "number" in the first paragraph.

Answer (score -2):

Simple trick to get 8 digits:

```
substr(your_number + power(10,8), 2)
```

Comment: Why would you do that rather than using a `to_char` with an appropriate format mask?

Comment: @JustinCave - Just for variety of answers.  Yes, `to_char(a_number, lpad('0',N,'0'))` is more reliable than `substr(a_number + power(10,N), 2)`.